# Shell Script - Input and Output File in C

Tags: shell, input, output

```
c_file=$( echo $2 | sed 's/\.c//g')
$c_file < $in_file > tempFile.out
```

Argument $5 is the path that takes me the a C program. ".c" of my C program name.
For example, the path:
/..../A3Solution.c

That will get me:

```
A3Solution < input.in > output.out
```

I got a run-time error:

> A3Solution: command not found

I don't know why, but it works when I run other C program in other path...
Any ideas on how I can change my program? I don't really see the problem. I've tried doing: `cat $5 and ls $5` so, I know the path of $5 is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that you're compiling the program, and putting the resulting executable in one of the folders listed in `$PATH`?

Comment: yup, I wrote something to compile the C program in my script. Let me check carefully now.

Comment: you're right. I think it's something about the compile line. After compiling my C program, the executable is not in the folder.

Comment: Wait, a.out is created after compiling....

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. If you're using `gcc` (or any of various similar compilers), you use the `-o` flag to specify the executable name: `gcc A3Solution.c -o A3Solution`.

Comment: `baseNameC=${2##*/}` and `c_file=${baseNameC%.c}`

Comment: a.out < input.in > output.out-------this will work. YAY

Answer (score 0):

the current path is usually not in the paths searched when running a program.
e.g.

```
$ ls -l bla
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 17036 13. Okt 2012  bla
$ bla
bash: bla: command not found
$
```

the trick is to tell your shell to look in the current directory, by prefixing `./`

```
$ ./bla
hello world
$
```

since you don't really know whether the file given will be in the current directory or in some other (unless you parse for '/') you could simply prefix the current-working directory (but then it won't work if you specify the absolute path) or use something like the `realpath` utility to canonicalize any relative path to an abolute path.

you also might awnt to use the power of bash (in case you are using that, to strip the trailing .c).
something like:

```
exe_file=$(realpath ${2%.c})
if [ -e "${exe_file}" ]; then
   "${exe_file}" < "${in_file}" > tempFile.out
else
   echo "file '$2' not found or not executable" 1>&2
fi
```